# How to replace chars in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java

I wrote a method which makes a map of chars of an input string, but I need that all spaces of this string has been put at the end of the map.

**Example of input :** "abc de"

**Example of output :**

```
"A" - quantity
"B" - quantity
"C" - quantity
"D" - quantity
"E" - quantity
" " - quantity
```

Here is my code:

```
public LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> output() {
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        char wordToLetter = inputString.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(wordToLetter)) {
            int quantity = map.get(wordToLetter);
            map.put(wordToLetter, ++quantity);
        } else {
            map.put(wordToLetter, 1);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Have a temporary counter for space, instead of adding it to the map, increase the counter and after the loop add it to the map

Comment: Another alternative solution is to remove the space entry if it exists and insert it back, linking it to the end of the `LinkedHashMap`. E.g. `if (map.containsKey(' ')) map.put(' ', map.remove(' '));`. Oleg's solution should be faster, however.

Comment: A `TreeMap` would be more suitable for this situation. Can you use a `TreeMap` instead, or can you afford to convert a `TreeMap` to `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: @Sweeper I was thinking for `TreeMap` but you will get `{ =1, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1}` instead of `{a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1,  =1}`

Comment: @YCF_L You can always provide your custom comparator that sorts spaces last...

Comment: In this case Yes.

Comment: If input is `"de abc"`, what order do you want the result in? `"D", "E", "A", "B", "C", " "`? Or `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", " "`? If the first, see comments by *Oleg* and *concision*. If the second, see the two comments by *Sweeper*.

Comment: if input is "de abc" I want to se smth like "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", " "

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution, based on the comments:

```
// Oleg's solution
public LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> output() {
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        char wordToLetter = inputString.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (wordLetter == ' ') {
            spaceCount++;
        } else if (map.containsKey(wordToLetter)) {
            int quantity = map.get(wordToLetter);
            map.put(wordToLetter, quantity + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(wordToLetter, 1);
        }
    }
    if (spaceCount > 0) {
        map.put(' ', spaceCount);
    }
    return map;
}
```

The trick is to not add the entry for spaces (if any) to the map until right at the end.  That means it will be the last entry.

We can actually optimize this as follows:

```
        ...
        } else if (map.containsKey(wordToLetter)) {
            int quantity = map.get(wordToLetter);
            map.put(wordToLetter, quantity + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(wordToLetter, 1);
        }
        ...
```

becomes

```
        ...
        } else {
            int quantity = map.getOrDefault(wordToLetter, 0);
            map.put(wordToLetter, quantity + 1);
        } 
        ...
```

This is more concise, and reduces the number of lookups.  Indeed, we can do even better:

```
        ...
        } else {
            map.compute(wordToLetter, i -> (i == null) ? 1 : i + 1);
        } 
        ...
```